# How to build soap to rest gateway

Tags: soap

How would you build a soap to rest gateway with the least amount of work? I provide a REST API on my Rails 3.2 server. My customer requires me to provide a SOAP API. I don't want to use Rails for providing the SOAP API since that would probably take much more work than building a SOAP to REST gateway using a framework that fully supports SOAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that Rails 3.2 parses SOAP requests automatically into the params hash (ActionDispatch::ParamsParser Rack middleware). So, I decided to  implement the gateway in Rails. Since I don't really care to implement a full featured SOAP Server--all I want is to make it work for my customer's current SOAP client--I will just read the data that I need from the params hash and build the xml response using Builder and publish a static wsdl file if they need it. It will be less than 20 lines of code.

config/routes.rb

```
Gateway::Application.routes.draw do
  match "/clientx/echo" => "clientx#echo"
end
```

app/controllers/clientx_controller.rb

```
class ClientxController < ApplicationController
  def echo
    # authenticate client
    # parse params
    # send and receive rest request
    # render response
  end
end
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem and I tried your code and it does not seem to work. I do not get any params in my echo action. Can you please let me know if you did anything else? I am using curl to send a soap request to my rails app.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Mule ESB](http://www.mulesoft.org)? Supports a various form of input and output possibilities. Implemented a SOAP-receiving application based on Mule myself.

Comment: thanks for the hint. they don't have pricing on their website and the sales person that i talked to said their smallest installation costs $14k. that's a bit more than i was hoping for.

Comment: But it's actually free!? Installation is dead simple. Only enterprise support costs you some money - but I don't think you're going to need it for the rather simple SOAP to REST forwarding.